# How to open new view when device is rotated to landscape orientation?

Tags: iphone, orientation, rotation, landscape, portrait

I have an application which is focused around a bunch of viewControllers in portraitmode, but on a specific detail view i need to open another view if the device is rotated to landscape mode.
So the user will look at the information view in portraitmode and if the user then rotates the device to landscapemode then a new view is displayed with additional information. If the user rotates back to portrait then the added view needs to be removed so the "original" detailview is visible.
It's important that the "original" detailview is not rotated to landscape - Only open a new view in landscape mode.

I've tried using shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: and managed to have it open a viewController, but it's not being shown in landscape view so it looks all messed up plus I'm having some trouble getting the view to disappear when i rotate back to portraitmode.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using shouldAutoRotate didn't work since the view that gets opened will be opened in portraitmode and not landscape.

I ended up with a solution using beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications and shouldAutoRotate in the subview.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the orientation has changed using the View controllers did change orientation methods and if its rotated to landscape add ur landscape view and when the device is rotated to portrait remove the view from the view controller's view.

Comment: No offense but thats more or less what i already said i wanted. What i need to know is HOW do i do it :) Specifically, how do i make sure the view i open/show is shown in landscape?

Comment: so have you created the landscape view?

Comment: I've tried several things - Atm. i have created a regular UIView but it's shown in portraitmode - I need to show it in landscape mode?

Comment: if u have created the view in nib, pls click the small arrow on the top-left hand corner this will rotate the view to landscape. If you have done through code check if the height is 320 and width is 480.

Comment: The view is created in code and setting the width to 480 doesn't rotate it to landscapemode. It's still shown in portraitmode - It's just to wide since i set the width to 480. I need it to be rotated properly to landscape.

Comment: ` horizontalImageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
 self.horizontalImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 self.horizontalImageView.hidden = YES;
 [self.view addSubview:self.horizontalImageView];`

Comment: I also have a viewController that i show with presentModalController - It shows just fine, but again it's shown in portraitmode and not landscape.

Answer (score 0):

in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
NewView *newViewController = [[NewView alloc]initWithNib:@"NewView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:NO];
}
```

you can repeat this for all the other orientations as well.

Comment: That was the first i tried and it doesn't work - The view that gets pushed will stay in portraitmode and not rotate to landscapemode like i need. But i found a solution for the problem after many many hours of messing around.

Comment: you need to set - `(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in the new class